# How to update state of child component when it get called in map function from parent component React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to show and hide menu from child component that could be in nth number.

The problem only happens when I split my code in child component.

**Use Case:** When I click the menu from one card it shows up, and when I click from another card it also shows up while the menu of card first stays active.

What I really want is, if I click from first card, it should shows up. Similarly, if I click from card second, it shows up and hide the opened menu of card first.
Basically, its working perfectly if I do not use child component of menu but when I start using a child component the above problem starts.

**Code:
Parent Comp:**

```js
    {chapters && chapters.map((chapter, index) =>
      <div className="card" key={chapter.id}>
       <ChapterActions
         {...this.state}
         chapterLists={true}
         chapterIndex={index}
         chapterId={chapter.id}
         deleteExistingChapterAction={this.deleteExistingChapterAction}
       />
      <div onClick={() => { this.getChapterDetailAction(chapter.course_id, chapter.id) }}>
      <div className={"subtitle"}>
          <i className="fas fa-book"/> 4 Kapitel
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
)}
```

**Child Comp (ChapterActions):**

```
    import React, {Component} from "react";
    
class ChapterActions extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
 showActions: false,
 }
 }
    
        componentDidMount() {
            const {chapterLists, chapterIndex, chapterId} = this.props;
            this.setState({chapterLists, chapterIndex, chapterId});
        }
    
        openDropdown = (event) => {
            const {showActions} = this.state;
            this.setState({showActions: showActions === event.target.id ? false : event.target.id})
        }
    
        render() {
            const {chapterLists, chapterIndex, showActions, chapterId} = this.state;
            return (
                <>
                    {chapterLists ? (
                        <>
                            <div className={'dropdown-div'} onClick={(event) => { this.openDropdown(event) }}>
                                <i className={"fa fa-ellipsis-v dropdown-icon"} id={`${chapterIndex}`} aria-hidden={"true"}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className={"dropdown-option-wrapper"} style={{display: `${chapterIndex}` === showActions ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
                                <div className={"dropdown-option"}>
                                    <span className={"select-name"}>
                                        <a onClick={() => {this.props.deleteExistingChapterAction(chapterId)}} data-confirm={"Möchten Sie den Kurs wirklich löschen?"}>
                                        <i className={"fas fa-trash"} aria-hidden={"true"}/><span className={"delete-span"}>Löschen</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </>
                    ) : (
                        ""
                    )}
                </>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default ChapterActions;
```

As a best practices its said that state should be managed in child component if we use child component but in my case is that logic is wrong?

Or what should be the best practices please?

Comment: anyone please? problem only arises when using child component.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show only one card the best way to keep state in the parent component.

For example

```
ParentComp -> 
state: openedChapterId = someId
setOpenedChapter(id) => setState({openedChapterId: id});
```

So, when you try to render your children you can able to compare currentID.

```
<ChapterActions isOpened={chapterId === openedChapterId} handleMenuClick={() => setOpenedChapter(chapterId)} />
```